# ExtJs moveAfter columns on a gridpanel is very slow

Tags: extjs, extjs6, gridpanel

I've a gridpanel with columns that can be dynamically re-ordered.

I use following method :

```
grid.headerCt.moveAfter
```

But when my array contains lot of columns, the loop (used to move columns) take lot of time to process (but not each time).
And in the meantime all the screen is frozen, even using suspendLayouts/resumeLayouts.

Here, my gridpanel contains 62 columns.
Sometimes the loop (used to move columns) ended after less than 1 second.
But many times, the loop ended after 12 or more seconds.

[image: moveAfter loop]

Is there a better way to make this but with best performance ?

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ExtJs 6.2.1

Comment: OK. I will try around a bit. How many rows does your grid have? Can you provide the column config?

Comment: I can have between some hundred and more than thousand rows. My array is fully dynamic, and columns are also defined according to the data. In fact, this array allows user to modified several data (of the same kind) in one time : each row is a instance of a record into database, and each column corresponds to a field of theses records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*MoveAfter* is increasingly slow if the number of rows and columns is large. processing time increase with the amount of data.

I have applied this workaround: moving columns on the array without rows, and adding rows after.

And now reordering columns take less of 1 second and do not evolve from one call to another.